# Error while decoding the protocol parameters

Tags: cardano-cli, blockchain, testnet, fee

This is occurring on testnet. Trying to calculate a fee for a transaction that will include metada.

Here's the script:

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
    --tx-body-file tx.draft \
    --tx-in-count 1 \
    --tx-out-count 1 \
    --witness-count 1 \
    --byron-witness-count 0 \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
    --protocol-params-file testnet-shelley-genesis.json
```

The error:

Command failed: transaction calculate-min-fee  Error: Error while decoding the protocol parameters at: "testnet-shelley-genesis.json" Error: "Error in $: key "protocolVersion" not found"

And the first part of the testnet-shelley-genesis.json file

```
{
  "activeSlotsCoeff": 0.05,
  "protocolParams": {
    "protocolVersion": {
      "minor": 0,
      "major": 2
    },
    "decentralisationParam": 1,
    "eMax": 18,
    "extraEntropy": {
      "tag": "NeutralNonce"
    },
    "maxTxSize": 16384,
    "maxBlockBodySize": 65536,
    "maxBlockHeaderSize": 1100,
    "minFeeA": 44,
    "minFeeB": 155381,
    "minUTxOValue": 1000000,
    "poolDeposit": 500000000,
    "minPoolCost": 340000000,
    "keyDeposit": 2000000,
    "nOpt": 150,
    "rho": 0.003,
    "tau": 0.20,
    "a0": 0.3
  },
```

Checked `byron` and `alonzo` genesis files and they do not contain the `protocolVersion` element. Haven't made any updates to any of the genesis files.

Is there a different params file I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the genesis file instead of the protocol-params-file.

Try using the protocol-params. You can get it using this command:

```
cardano-cli query protocol-parameters --testnet-magic 1097911063 > protocol-params.json
```

It works:

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
--tx-body-file tx.draft \
--protocol-params-file protocol-params.json \
--testnet-magic 1097911063 \
--tx-in-count 1 \
--tx-out-count 1 \
--witness-count 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The tutorial specifically said protocol-params.json, but since I couldn't find it from the download sites, I thought maybe the tutorial had it wrong, so I assumed one of the genesis files.  That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest files from https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7654130/download/1/index.html

There was an update did you update your node? You should also get the latest config files